# How to make Nintendo Switch work with any USB-LAN Adapter with the AX88179 chipset?

Tags: nintendo-switch, networking

**DISCLAIMER**
I don't know if this is the right community, if not please move it to the right.
I am not an expert, but I will give my best to provide necessary information.
I am just curious whats going on and if its possible to get it work.

As described in [Why does the Nintendo Switch only work with USB-LAN Adapters with the AX88179 chipset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365484/why-does-the-nintendo-switch-only-work-with-usb-lan-adapters-with-the-ax88179-ch) by user1686 the Nintendo Switch should work with any USB-LAN Adapter with the AX88179 chipset. But also the user described that it is possible that Nintendo can block certain models with that chipset.

I bought a USB-LAN Adapter with the AX88179 chipset, it it recognized by Ubuntu 18.04, but not by the Nintendo Switch.

dmesg tells:

```
[ 2745.220724] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2745.370933] usb 3-7: unable to get BOS descriptor or descriptor too short
[ 2745.372513] usb 3-7: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has an invalid bInterval 0, changing to 7
[ 2745.375410] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790
[ 2745.375416] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2745.375420] usb 3-7: Product:  ÎÈÇåk\xc2\x90
[ 2745.375423] usb 3-7: Manufacturer:  ÎÈÇåk\xc2\x90\xc2\x95
                                                             ·s
[ 2745.375425] usb 3-7: SerialNumber:  ÎÈÇåk\xc2\x90\xc2\x95
                                                             ·s
[ 2745.708853] ax88179_178a 3-7:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-7, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, a0:ce:c8:c7:e5:6b
[ 2745.740212] ax88179_178a 3-7:1.0 enxa0cec8c7e56b: renamed from eth0
[ 2745.761225] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxa0cec8c7e56b: link is not ready
[ 2746.089436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxa0cec8c7e56b: link is not ready
```

ethtool dumps the following:

```
$ sudo ethtool -e enxa0cec8c7e56b
Offset      Values
------      ------
0x0000:     a0 ce c8 c7 e5 6b 90 17 95 0b b7 73 00 00 3e 01 
0x0010:     00 00 00 00 00 07 00 10 00 0e 00 00 41 58 38 38 
0x0020:     31 37 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0030:     00 00 00 00 41 53 49 58 20 45 6c 65 63 2e 20 43 
0x0040:     6f 72 70 2e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 30 30 30 
0x0050:     30 30 30 30 30 30 30 44 34 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0060:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0070:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x0080:     00 00 00 00 c1 bd ff ff ff ff 00 00 ff ff ff ff 
0x0090:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00a0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00b0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00c0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00d0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00e0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
0x00f0:     ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 

$ sudo ethtool -w enxa0cec8c7e56b
Can not get dump level
: Operation not supported

$ sudo ethtool -d enxa0cec8c7e56b
Cannot get register dump: Operation not supported

$ sudo ethtool -m enxa0cec8c7e56b
Cannot get module EEPROM information: Operation not supported
```

Is it my fault or Nintendo blocks or does not recognize for whatever reason my device?
Has it something to do with the unicode characters in the Product, Manufacturer or SerialNumber?
If it is on Nintendo, is it possible to flash the Adapter so the Nintendo Switch can recognize it?